# Asp.net compile js in class library as embedded resource with c# code inside

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, embedded-resource

In my class library i'm embedding some js and css files for use in my asp.net application, as in the method described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398930.aspx).
Now i would to put some c# code inside js file, and let it compile in the resulting dll.
Would it be possibile?

Example: somefile.js

```
function foo() 
{
    var a = "<%= SOME_CONSTANT_DECLARED_OUTSIDE %>";
    <% ... some conditional code %>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is client SIDE and C# is server side .

You can't run C# in Javascript

Comment: thats not completely true. thats as you would say, you cannot use C# in HTML. But an ascx file IS a HTML file but running through a C# view template interpreter

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET does not compile, nor look for managed code (code that compiles, like C# code) in *.js files. SO when you put some C# code in js file, that code will not work as C# code (the client will try to use it as javascript code).

But there is a workaround - 
ASP.NET **does** render C# code in aspx files. So you can embed some C# code in JS function, as long as this function located in aspx file (inside script tags).

Answer (score 0):

The documentation tells you a way how to add a variable..-

In the UpdatePanelAnimation.js you have this lines of code

```
BorderAnimation = function(color) {
    this._color = color;
}
```

this is then automatically set.

```
Dim script As String = String.Format( _
               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, _
               "Sys.Application.add_load(function(sender, args) {{var {0}_borderAnimation = new BorderAnimation('{1}');var panelElement = document.getElementById('{0}');if (args.get_isPartialLoad()) {{{0}_borderAnimation.animate(panelElement);}}}});", _
               updatePanel.ClientID, _
               ColorTranslator.ToHtml(BorderColor))


        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript( _
            Me, _
            GetType(UpdatePanelAnimationWithClientResource), _
            ClientID, _
            script, _
            True)
```

So the formatted `{1}` is replaced with BorderColor that you have on the server side.
You might now want to update the JS constructor like this

BorderAnimation = function(color, otherValue) {
    this._color = color;
    this._otherValue = otherValue
}

now you do the same with the server side formatting but then you do

```
...
var {0}_borderAnimation = new BorderAnimation('{1}', '{2}')
...
```

this is the way how ASP.NET kind of 'connects' Backend with Frontend.
There are some other ways (more elegant) to do that, but thats not the question :)